# Kendo UI [kendoDropDownList] - onSelect optionLable, add CSS class

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using KendoDropDownList for my project and replacing the select box options from script.

I want to add css class **placeholder** if I select optionLable (`-- Please select --`)

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/icIdI)**

Please check the below reference image what I am talking about..

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectBox" data-bind="value: index, source: newOptions">
  <option>{Label 1}</option>
  <option>{Label 2}</option>
  <option>{Label 3}</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$("#selectBox").kendoDropDownList({
  valuePrimitive: true,
  dataTextField: "text",
  dataValueField: "value",
  optionLabel: "-- Please select --"
});
var icsNew = kendo.observable({
  index: 2,
  newOptions: [
    { value: 1, text: "My option 1" },
    { value: 2, text: "My option 2" },
    { value: 3, text: "My option 3" } ]
});
kendo.bind($("#selectBox"), icsNew);
```

**CSS**

```
.k-dropdown{border:1px solid #ccc;}
.placeholder{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `optionLabelTemplate`:

```
$("#selectBox").kendoDropDownList({
    ...
    optionLabel: "-- Please select --",
    optionLabelTemplate:'<span style="color:red">-- Please select --</span>',
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi **@Gene R**, thanks for the answer.. but still not working... please check the updated demo... **http://dojo.telerik.com/AbIyI**

Comment: @Reddy do not remove `optionLabel`

Comment: Thanks **Gene R**... it is working as expected... but should I need to maintain placeholder in 2 places?... `optionLabel: "-- Please select --",
        optionLabelTemplate:'<span style="color:red">-- Please select --</span>'` ... please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @Reddy yes, but it works even if optionLabel is empty space: `optionLabel: " "`

Comment: Thanks again.. I am accepting your answer and upvoting :)